# Reset Google Play password

Tags: google-play-store

I forgot my son's password to filter which apps he download through the Google Play Store. How can I reset it?

Comment: Is it about Play Store parental control, or Google Play Store account?

Answer (score 0):

Play Store is connected with your **gmail/google account**, you need to check by which account you use Google play Store and **reset password for google/Gmail account** as followed by Google instruction.

Hope it will help you.please Update me if any help you need.

Answer (score 0):

The way Android Works is all the Google Services on the deivce by default run on a single gmail account,What I mean is your playstore gmail account is by default used with other google services like google play music google play games etc

if you want to reset your google play store password you need to reset your email password this will automatically logout of the playstore and ask you to sign in with a new password.